# How do I build/deploy a Blazor app to desktop using Electron.NET?

Tags: electron, blazor, electron.net

I am attempting to build/deploy a Blazor app to desktop using Electron.NET. I have one Visual Studio 2022 solution containing a Blazor project and an Electron.NET project.

Following along with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWtHE7etTRA&list=PLuiZbe9d0AhjsphndRxybqGtqIwVa4BXC&index=3&t=977s&ab_channel=LandanParker
I am able to use Visual Studio 2022 to publish the Blazor project into the Electron.NET project's **/obj/Host/bin** directory.

Running `electronize start` from the Electron.NET project root will then launch the Electron.NET project 100% perfect, with all of my Blazor code running without issue.

Running `electronize build /target win` from the Electron.NET project root will build the project into the **/bin/Desktop** directory. Then, upon running the produced .exe, the app installs to my Windows machine and launches. *However*, the Electron.NET app displays a blank screen, implying that none of the Blazor app source code was properly included during the build.

[image]

Has anyone run into this or a similar situation before? I've followed along with the build output and can't find where it would be missing the Blazor source code. Perhaps there is another directory I should be publishing the Blazor source code to, such that `electronize build /target win` can then find it?